# Does jellyfish contian heme or non-heme iron

Tags: nutrient-composition

Is the iron in jellyfish heme or non-heme iron? I would like to eat jellyfish as an alternative to red meat and know that I am getting a good source of iron in my diet.

Comment: Hello Autumn and welcome! Don't have time to write a proper answer right now but, as jellyfish don't have blood, any iron from them wouldn't be heme iron.

Comment: @Cindy thanks for the response. Damn. Oh well, it still seems like a good meat to eat instead of beef.

Comment: We don't have a "wierdest question of the month" award, but if we did, you would win.  Maybe eat that squid with some spinach.  It's nonheme, but it has a lot of iron.  Welcome to SA!